# Python HTTPS server - Certificate validation

Tags: python, ssl, curl

I need to create simple https server with Python. I've used this tutorial https://www.piware.de/2011/01/creating-an-https-server-in-python/ and it works with one small "but".

When i try to curl my server (ex. curl -vvv https://domain.com) response looks similar to:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate More details here: LINK

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is your question? Looks like it works as it's supposed to.

Comment: No it don't. As i wrote before when i try to connect via curl or simple php script i have error with certificate validation.

Comment: You need to read up on TLS and how certs work with it.  Perhaps here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using your complete certificate chain instead of only your certificate (and your key) on your script:

```
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='/path/to/fullchain.pem', server_side=True,  keyfile='/path/to/server.key')
```

If you're using a self-signed certificate, cURL won't accept it unless you install it on your local CA certs or run cURL with `-k`:

```
curl -vvvk https://domain.com
```

The certificate chain is just a series of certificates, from your local issued up to the global (including intermediates), CAs usually provide it.